# How to delete files from Firebase storage while deleting a document that has reference for that file?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Angular App, it includes items each item has its image uploaded on Firebase storage and has an img property that refers to the URL of the image.
I want to delete the image while deleting the document, how to do it properly?

Comment: To delete files, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/delete-files. If you're having problems making that work, edit your question to include the [minimal, complete, standalone that reproduces the problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You should probably write an answer following this JavaScript SDK approach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a Cloud Function triggered via the `onDelete` event, see  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events.

Then, in the Cloud Function, you would use the [Google Cloud Storage Node.js Client API](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.5.x/) to delete the file in Cloud Storage.

Let's imagine that `bucket` and `name` are fields of the Firestore document that hold the file bucket and name (i.e. "img property that reference to the URL of the image"), then you could do something along the following lines:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const defaultStorage = admin.storage();


exports.deleteFile = functions.firestore
    .document('fileDocuments/{fileDocID}')
    .onDelete((snap, context) => {
      const deletedValue = snap.data();
      const fileBucket = deletedValue.bucket;
      const fileName = deletedValue.name;

      return defaultStorage
        .bucket(fileBucket)
        .file(fileName)
        .delete();

});
```

You may study the following official Cloud Functions sample or documentation items:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.5.x/File#delete

Comment: so how to actually use this in an angular app?

Comment: @OmarAbdelhady You may have a look at the solution proposed by Frank, in the comment to your question. It is actually an easier solution, which consists in deleting the file from your app through the JavaScript SDK (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/delete-files). The solution based on Cloud Function, as proposed in my answer, is probably not necessary and is more complex.